# How do I find font name of bold text in Word with C#

Tags: c#, xml, fonts, ms-word

I am trying to get all used fonts and bold text's fonts in many docx files.

Now I can get all used fonts by unzip docx file and read fontTable.xml.

```
if (fontfile.Name.Equals("fontTable.xml"))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fontfile.FullName, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    string pattern = "<w:font w:name=.+?>";
                    Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
                    MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(content);
                    foreach (Match match in matches)
                    {
                        string fontname = match.ToString().Replace("<w:font w:name=\"","").Replace("\">","");
                        fontlist.Add(fontname);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
```

But I don't know how to get bold text's font.
I tried unzip docx file and get bold text's font in document.xml, but cannot find the connection between document.xml and fontTable.xml.

In fontTable.xml, I can find used font names of current file, but no bold information.

```
<w:font w:name="Calibri"><w:panose1 w:val="020F0502020204030204"/><w:charset w:val="00"/><w:family w:val="swiss"/><w:pitch w:val="variable"/><w:sig w:usb0="E0002AFF" w:usb1="C000247B" w:usb2="00000009" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="000001FF" w:csb1="00000000"/></w:font>
```

I can find bold information in document.xml with "w:b/" or "w:bCs/" in "w:r" tag.
But no font name in document.xml

```
<w:r w:rsidRPr="00C22891"><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:hint="eastAsia"/><w:b/><w:bCs/></w:rPr><w:t>加粗</w:t></w:r>
```

I tried Microsoft.office.interop, if I search file with `bold== true` and a font name, the `isFind` is always `false`.

```
app.Selection.Find.Font.Bold = -1; //true
                        //app.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
                        app.Selection.Find.Font.NameAscii = fontname;
                        app.Selection.Find.Forward = true;
                        isFind = app.Selection.Find.Execute("", nothing, nothing, nothing, nothing, nothing, app.Selection.Find.Forward, nothing,
                         app.Selection.Find.Font.Bold, nothing, nothing, nothing, nothing, nothing, nothing);
                        if (isFind)
                        {
                            font_list_bold.Add(fontname + "+Bold");
                        }
```

So I am wondering if there is any way to get all fonts of bold text in Word

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: when you can, edit your post and show us a small sample of the xml you are trying to parse -

Comment: I added 2 screenshots about document.xml and fontTable.xml
Please refer to them if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Please post code and error messages a **text** content, not as images. Images are not always easy to read and can't be copied/pasted for repro purposes.

Comment: One problem you're going to have with this is that it depends how bold formatting was applied. It might be part of a style definition, such as "Heading 1". In cases such as this the code would need to check all style definitions whether bold is part of them then search whether the styles have been used in the document. Or bold may have been applied directly to the text - in this case it needs to be searched in document.xml.

Comment: Associating bold with a font will depend on the same kinds of factors: if it's part of a style and no direct formatting has been applied over it (the user hasn't changed the font formatting), the font needs to be extracted from the style definition. If the user applied a font then the information is in the document.xml.

Comment: A tip for using the site: if you need to reply to someone in comments it's important to "ping" them by putting an `@` before the name. For example, to "ping" me: @CindyMeister

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, @CyindyMeister. except unzip docx, is there any way to do this?